# Can't send checklist to email from html

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I need to do a simple script with two parts. First one is sending just name, phone number etc. and works perfectly already:

But after it i need to  send a checklist to the same email, but still is nothing there.

My html:

```html
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="form" class="contact-form">
  <table style="color: DEB441; font-size: 19px; margin-left: 60px; margin-top: 40px; float: left;">
    <tr>
      <td><font color="FFFFFF">Imie:</td>
      <td style="padding:0px">
        <textarea style="outline-color: DEB441;  margin-left: 23px; margin-bottom: 5px; overflow:auto;width:269px;height:15px;border:1px solid #DEB441;background:#fff;padding:3px 5px;color:#3D1E09;font:14px;font-style:italic;margin:0" name="cf_imie" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><font color="FFFFFF">Nazwisko:</td>
      <td style="padding:0px">
        <textarea style="outline-color: DEB441;  margin-left: 23px; margin-bottom: 5px; overflow:auto;width:269px;height:15px;border:1px solid #DEB441;background:#fff;padding:3px 5px;color:#3D1E09;font:14px;font-style:italic;margin:0" name="cf_nazwisko" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><font color="FFFFFF">Adres:</td>
      <td style="padding:0px">
        <textarea style="outline-color: DEB441;  margin-left: 23px; margin-bottom: 5px; overflow:auto;width:269px;height:15px;border:1px solid #DEB441;background:#fff;padding:3px 5px;color:#3D1E09;font:14px;font-style:italic;margin:0" name="cf_adres" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><font color="FFFFFF">Telefon</td>
      <td style="padding:0px">
        <textarea style="outline-color: DEB441;  margin-left: 23px; margin-bottom: 5px; overflow:auto;width:269px;height:15px;border:1px solid #DEB441;background:#fff;padding:3px 5px;color:#3D1E09;font:14px;font-style:italic;margin:0" name="cf_telefon" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><font color="FFFFFF">E-mail:</td>
      <td style="padding:0px">
        <textarea style="outline-color: FFFFFF;  margin-left: 23px; margin-bottom: 5px; overflow:auto;width:269px;height:15px;border:1px solid #DEB441;background:#fff;padding:3px 5px;color:#3D1E09;font:14px;font-style:italic;margin:0" name="cf_email" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 150px;">
        <p style="align: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 10px;"><br>
          <font style="font-size: 16px;" color="#FFFFFF" align="left">
    
          Wybierz produkty:<br><br>
    
          <font style="font-size: 12px;" color="#FFFFFF" align="left">
    
          Herbatniki w pudelkach <br>
          <hr align="left" width="110px"><bt>
          <input type="checkbox" name="thenderese" value="thenderese" />Thenderese<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="petipa" value="petipa" />Petipa<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="biscripts" value="biscripts" />Biscripts<br>
        </p>
      </td> 
      <td style="width: 150px;">
        <p style="width: 250px; align: left;"><br>
          <font style="font-size: 12px;" color="#FFFFFF" align="left">

          Herbatniki Pakowane pojedynczo<br>
          <hr align="left" width="160px">

          <input type="checkbox" name="6g" value="g6g" />6g
          <input type="checkbox" name="150g" value="g150g" />150g
          <input type="checkbox" name="300g" value="g300g" />300g
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 200px; margin-right: 250px;">
        <p align="left" style="align: left; margin-top:0px;"><br>
          <font style="font-size: 12px;" color="#FFFFFF" align="left">

          Inne
          <hr  align="left" width="150px">
      
          <input type="checkbox" name="folia" value="folia">Biscripts opakowane w folie<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="speculoos1" value="speculoos1" />1,5 kg (proszek speculoos)<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="speculoos2" value="speculoos2" />1,1 kg (pokruszony speculoos)<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="krem" value="krem biscripts" />krem biscripts<br>
        </p>
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

and my PHP

```html
<?php
$field_imie = $_POST['cf_imie'];
$field_nazwisko = $_POST['cf_nazwisko'];
$field_adres = $_POST['cf_adres'];
$field_telefon = $_POST['cf_telefon'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'serwis@reskomp.pl';
$subject = 'nowe zamowienie '.$field_imie;

$body_message = 'Od: '.$field_imie."\n";
$body_message .= 'Nazwisko: '.$field_nazwisko."\n";
$body_message .= 'Adres: '.$field_adres."\n";
$body_message .= 'Telefon: '.$field_telefon."\n";
$body_message .= 'Email: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Szczegoly zamowienia: '.$field_message;


$thenderese = $_POST['thenderese'];
if ($thenderese != 'Yes') {
    $thenderese = 'No';
}
 $petipa = $_POST['petipa'];
if ($petipa != 'Yes') {
    $petipa = 'No';
}
 $biscripts = $_POST['biscripts'];
if ($biscripts != 'Yes') {
    $biscripts = 'No';
}
 $g6g = $_POST['6g'];
if ($g6g != 'Yes') {
    $g6g = 'No';
}
 $g150g = $_POST['150g'];
if ($g150g != 'Yes') {
    $g150g = 'No';
}
 $g300g = $_POST['300g'];
if ($g300g != 'Yes') {
    $g300g = 'No';
}
$folia = $_POST['folia'];
if ($folia != 'Yes') {
    $folia = 'No';
}
$speculoos1 = $_POST['speculoos1'];
if ($speculoos1 != 'Yes') {
    $speculoos1 = 'No';
}
$speculoos2 = $_POST['speculoos2'];
if ($speculoos2 != 'Yes') {
    $speculoos2 = 'No';
}
$krem = $_POST['krem'];
if ($krem != 'Yes') {
    $krem = 'No';
}

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);


if ($mail_status) { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Zamowienie zostalo przyjete do realizacji.');
  window.location = '../herbatniki/index.html';
 </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Blad wysylania wiadomosci. Prosimy o kontakt na adres: coo.maan@gmail.com');
  window.location = 'Contacts.html';
 </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

If somebody could help me...
I know that i should use more css, but this is not the reason.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what is missing? the "No / Yes" things?

Comment: Everything. My emails looks like this:

<<<Od: 
Nazwisko: 
Adres: 
Telefon: 
Email: 
Szczegoly zamowienia:>>>

And nothing below

Comment: Are you 'POSTING' the form?  Or are you hijacking the form submission with javascript and using GET? Try dumping the body message before the mail.  Looks like it's absent of post data.

Comment: How do you even submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have no way to submit your form.

Further, to add your checkbox data to your email message, you can use something like the following.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    var_dump($_POST);
    $message = '';
    $message .= sprintf("Name: %s\n", isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '');
    $message .= sprintf("Foo wanted: %s\n", isset($_POST['foo']) ? 'Yes' : 'No');
    $message .= sprintf("Bar wanted: %s\n", isset($_POST['bar']) ? 'Yes' : 'No');
    var_dump($message);
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    Your Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" />You want Foo?<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="bar" />You want Bar?<br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

However please research 'email injection in php'.

Comment: but where should i write my email adres?

Comment: Hey Progrock, could you tell me one more thing?
How to send it to email adres?

Comment: You have an example of the php mail function in your original code submission.  But again, please read up about email injection.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the content to `$body_message`.

Change

```
$thenderese = $_POST['thenderese'];
if ($thenderese != 'Yes') {
    $thenderese = 'No';
}
```

to

```
$thenderese = $_POST['thenderese'];
$body_message .= 'thenderese';
if ($thenderese != 'Yes') {
    $body_message .= 'No';
}
else {
    $body_message .= 'Yes';
}
$body_message .= '/n';
```

and continue for the rest of your `if` statements.

Comment: Now my emails looks like this: <<<Od: Jakub
Nazwisko: Jakas
Adres: Adresowaty
Telefon: 700 700 700
Email: 700@sweety.com
Szczegoly zamowienia: NoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNo>>>

Comment: Why would this help, the checkbox values are never 'Yes'?

Comment: <<<<Od: 
Nazwisko: sdf
Adres: asd
Telefon: 
Email: 
Szczegoly zamowienia: thendereseNo/npetipaNo/>>>>>